# using incremental annotation processing with kapt and maven plugin for kotlin

Tags: java, android, maven, kotlin, kapt

How can we use  incremental annotation processing with maven plugin?

Documentation only tells about gradle:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#incremental-annotation-processing-since-1330

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, the maven part is right below from what you've linked: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#using-in-maven

Comment: but how can i achieve gradle option like: kapt.incremental.apt=true in maven config in pom.xml?

Comment: *Incremental annotation processing is enabled by default starting from version 1.3.50.*, so if you use that version or above it should be enabled by default

Comment: ok ;-) thank you - didn´t know. i was wondering why kapt was so slow...

Comment: Voting to close: The issue solved itself by time, if I understand correctly - the KAPT incremental is now on by default.